# Collision Issues

Tags: xna, 3d, collision-detection, xna-4.0

When I run the collision code, there are no errors, but when I shoot the enemy nothing happens..... Any problems that are blindingly obvious?

Class Level Variables

```
public Model model { get; protected set; }
```

Collision Code

```
        public bool CollidesWith(Model otherModel, Matrix otherWorld)
    {
        // Loop through each ModelMesh in both objects and compare
        // all bounding spheres for collisions
        foreach (ModelMesh myModelMeshes in model.Meshes)
        {
            foreach (ModelMesh hisModelMeshes in otherModel.Meshes)
            {
                if (myModelMeshes.BoundingSphere.Transform(
                    GetWorld()).Intersects(
                    hisModelMeshes.BoundingSphere.Transform(otherWorld)))
                    return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: You should do some debugging. Create an obvious "hit" scenario, and see if the bounding sphere positions are right. I think the transformations might not be correct.

Comment: One thing I find really useful is adding `Debugger.Break()` (or throwing an exception) for methods when "nothing happens." That helps troubleshoot real fast (eg. not building in `Any CPU` so can't debug easily).

Comment: Note your `myModelMeshes.BoundingSphere.Transform(GetWorld())` should be saved in a variable -- it only needs to be done _once_ per iteration of the outer loop, not repeatedly in the inner loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems to me that you are not applying the bone transforms.

If you are going to evaluate collisions this way, it would be much better to calculate the absolute bounding spheres in `world` coordinates. This way you avoid to repeat transformations.

```
 class MyModel {
       public Model Model;
       public Matrix MyWorld;
       public BoundingSphere[] Bounds;
       public Matrix[] MeshTransform;

       public void CalculateAbsoluteBounds() {
           Matrix[] transforms = new Matrix[Model.Bones.Count];
           Model.CopyAbsoluteBoneTransformsTo(transforms);

           for (int i=0; i<Model.Meshes.Count; i++)
           {
              // You can use MeshTransform to draw the model...
              Matrix.Multiply( ref transforms[Model.Meshes[i].ParentBone.Index], 
                               ref MyWorld, 
                               out MeshTransform[i]); 
              // Transform bounding sphere now with MeshTransform
              Model.Meshes[i].BoundingSphere.Transform(
                   ref MeshTransform[i], out Bounds[i]);     
           }
       }
 }
```

And it would be a great idea to draw `wireframe` spheres to debug them easily

Comment: When i try that I get 3 errors, which are:

  Error 1 The best overloaded method match for 'Microsoft.Xna.Framework.BoundingSphere.Transform(ref Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Matrix, out Microsoft.Xna.Framework.BoundingSphere)' has some invalid arguments

  Error 2 Argument 1 must be passed with the 'ref' keyword 

  Error 3 Argument 2 must be passed with the 'out' keyword

Comment: I wrote this without testing ... I have edited the code...